# Limit the total number of entries displayed in the Datatable

Tags: php, datatable, large-data

I have a history table with 3700000+ entries. I am using server-side processing in the datatable to initially display 25 records. It is taking lots of time to initially load the datatable even though the query fetches only 25 records.

I am using MySQL database. Now I want to limit the total number of entries from which the data should be processed. I want only past 15 days entries to be considered.

Is there a way by which I can load the table quickly?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you posted the code that you are currently trying to use so that we can get a better understanding of what you need.

Comment: You can filter results in sql where clause.

Comment: You can use Server-side processing and load partial data, just like we do in pagination

Comment: Try to minimize fields in your select list if you are not using after retrieving.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can limit how much data you get back from a SQL Query.

Using `WHERE` will allow you to only select entries after a certain date.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE date > ".strtotime("-15 days");
```

The above query assumes that in your history database you have a date that is a unix based timestamp. Another way that you could limit the amount of data that is returned is by using the `LIMIT` function.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM history ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15";
```

This query assumes that you only have one entry per day, and will limit it to only 15 entries to be displayed.

Along with this, if your history table has a lot of data that doesn't need to be used, then you can only select the columns that you need, doing something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, time, name FROM history";
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE `created_date`>= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 15 DAY)